# How to deploy ionic 2 to browser

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I see Cordova has a browser platform, I suppose it is for deploying to browser, also `ionic serve` uses browser to test.

But this is for development, for production, what is the correct way to deploy a Ionic 2 app to a web server for browsers? Which folder(s) do I have to upload with FTP and at which index do I have to point?

Thanks in advance

Comment: For production, you should generate APK file for Android and IPA file for IOS  device. why do you want to deploy IONIC as a web-based site for production?

Comment: I want to build a web client too for the app, it is cheaper to publish on web than re-make all in web version

Comment: You must be really out of your mind! Using Ionic for building a website. Any decent UX designer would disagree with you. Not to mention that Ionic applications are not meant for the web & I mean by that they're too big for a web application. If your users were to use smart-phones to access your web page that would take them a hell of a time!

Comment: "Ionic applications are not meant for the web" not true. Ionic (2+) apps are great for Progressive Web Apps, which runs on the browser.

Comment: Yes, it is very heavy for a web app, this is the bad point, for the rest it is ok for a web app

Comment: @Melchia you can absolutely deploy an Ionic app to the web, either as a PWA or otherwise https://ionicframework.com/pwa

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony Yes I know that you can. But I was talking about the user experience. Ionic bundles are too large! Not to mention that Cordova shouldn't be used & must be replaced with web APIs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you have to add browser platform to cordova

Then run the build for browser

```
ionic build --prod browser
```

it will generate the folder

```
platforms/browser/
```

the content of 
*platforms/browser/www/* is the output.
You can host it the way you like, it is a "static site". Example: using Apache or nginx.

Comment: This command builds for the Cordova browser platform, which isn't (currently) supported by Ionic and not recommeded. Instead you should build the app outside of Cordova using `ionic build --prod` and just serve the www folder. It's very confusing between the "browser platform" that Cordova offers and just the plain regular browser that web apps are built for

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony Can you refer some page with explicitely tells to not use cordova browser platform and use www instead? Are you meaning platforms/browser/www/ or the ionic serve www? It seems not standard

Comment: I've only seen it mentioned in comment on Github issues, for example: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/13248#issuecomment-339631296

Answer (score 0):

Hello if you want to deploy your ionic app as a website then you don't need to add Cordova support for this. You can simply build the website in a production mode with default ionic script.

> Synopsis

```
$ ionic build
```

> Option

```
--prod       Build the application for production

--aot        Perform ahead-of-time compilation for this build

--minifyjs   Minify JS for this build

--minifycss  Minify CSS for this build

--optimizejs Perform JS optimizations for this build
```

> Examples

```
$ ionic build 
$ ionic build --prod
```